# How to remove a duplicate HTML element with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got into a trouble that my code had been created three times with IE 8 without any reason...
However, it works well with FF and Chrome. Please let me know how I can remove the duplicate?

**My Javascript:**

```
var get_text_approve_2 = "Transportation";
$(get_approve_2).after("<a class='set_backgr' href=''>" + get_text_approve_2 + "</a>");
```

**HTML:**

- **In FF & Chrome - I got:**

  `<a href="" class="set_backgr">Transportation</a>`
- **In IE 8 - I got:**

  `<A class=set_backgr href="">Transportation </A>
  <A class=set_backgr href="">Transportation </A>`

Comment: Share your complete JS function and HTMl

Comment: you should use $().before() and  $().after()

Comment: **@KamleshKushwaha**: I would but I thought the IE 8 caused problem.

Comment: Rather than trying to remove the duplicated elements, you might want to find out why the duplicated elements appeared in the first place.

Comment: **@pramod.nikam.dev**: How can I put `$().before` into this situation?

Comment: @PMay1903 Unless you share the HTML code, we cannot know the exact reason. However there are many fixes and hacks to avoid this and you can see them in the answers below, but that's not the way to solve the problem.

Comment: **@KamleshKushwaha**: That's true but it is all in SharePoint. Thus, the IE 8 might cause the problem and I am looking for the way to remove the duplicate because there was only one `$().after` in my code. Sorry for this inconvenience because they look like a messy.

Comment: try `$('.set_backgr').slice(1).remove()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
while($(".set_backgr").length > 1)
    $(".set_backgr:first").remove()
```

however is more helpful understand why there is a duplicate.

Comment: i have added a condition. why two?

Comment: Replace if with while :)

Comment: I have tried with your first code so this removed two... Let me tried again with your edited code.

Comment: That's great. This solved my problem now. It separated my code with the difference between IE 8 and FF. Thank you very much.

Comment: **@Silviu Burcea**: Could you please tell me the different role between `if` and `while` here?

Answer (score 1):

Try using .slice()

```
$('.set_backgr').slice(0, -1).remove()
```

Comment: That works pretty well as your above comment. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try

[:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

[:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/)

```
$('.set_backgr:not(:last)').remove();
```

---

`$('.set_backgr:not(:last)')` select all elements with class `set_backgr` except the last one.

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/t3nRq/)</kbd>
<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo with only one element**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/t3nRq/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you! Both your code and explanation are quite impressive. I appreciate your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

you might have include twice this file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

please check it

Comment: There are `<script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">My script goes here!</script>
`. Yet I don't know why...

Comment: are you using master page ?

Comment: **@Sunny_Sid**: That's it. However, it is SharePoint's master page and I don't think this affected to the JS.